# How well is Objective-J documented? Is the documentation good enough to start using it seriously?

Tags: javascript, cappuccino, objective-j

I consider going with Objective-J, instead writing plain JavaScript. But I wonder if the documentation of the language and the frameworks is good enough, since it seems like a very young development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Been trying it for future development. One thing for sure, it is intended for web "apps" instead of web "sites".

Documentations are lacking at this moment I think but the mailing list is active. The only docs & howtos I can find are in the official site.

Very young development indeed.

Answer (score 10):

The API is also the same as Cocoa, so for instance, looking at developer.apple.com for NSView will be suitable as docs for CPView.

Answer (score 2):

Cappuccino’s documentation is generated with `doxygen` and you can always summon `jake docs` to build a local copy.

Definitely look into the mailing list.

Comment: The jake docs / doxygen documentation is less than useful. Methods missing for all the common classes (Check out CPString).